WooCommerce blocks checkout custom gateway
I've a custom payment gateway and working to support the new Blocks checkout by adding class.
I'm able to render the checkout in edit page of Wordpress but the same is not showing if I try a real scenario.
This is the edit checkout page screenshot where I'm able to see the method after supporting the blocks checkout with a new class

When I try it in the checkout page it doesn't show up.

Added the below code to support existing plugin for blocks checkout
add_action( 'before_woocommerce_init', 'portone_cart_checkout_blocks_compatibility' );

function portone_cart_checkout_blocks_compatibility() {

    if( class_exists( '\Automattic\WooCommerce\Utilities\FeaturesUtil' ) ) {
        \Automattic\WooCommerce\Utilities\FeaturesUtil::declare_compatibility(
            'cart_checkout_blocks',
            __FILE__,
            false // true (compatible, default) or false (not compatible)
        );
    }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_blocks_loaded', 'portone_gateway_block_support' );
function portone_gateway_block_support() {

     if( ! class_exists( 'Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\Payments\Integrations\AbstractPaymentMethodType' ) ) {
        return;
     }

    // here we're including our "gateway block support class"
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/portoneBlocks.php';

    // registering the PHP class we have just included
    add_action(
        'woocommerce_blocks_payment_method_type_registration',
        function( Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\Payments\PaymentMethodRegistry $payment_method_registry ) {
            $payment_method_registry->register( new WC_Portone_Gateway_Blocks_Support );
        }
    );

}


I found the error. In the javascript code – gatewayBlockOptions.name must be same as the id of the actual gateway
I hope this will spend someone few hours 

Here are the specific codes for three files, you can refer to them.
fugpay.php
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'fugpay_gateway_init', 0);
function fugpay_gateway_init() {
    if( !class_exists('WC_Payment_Gateway') )
        return;
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'fugpay', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/lang/'  );
    require_once( plugin_basename( 'class-wc-fugpay.php' ) );
    add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'woocommerce_fugpay_add_gateway' );

    add_action('before_woocommerce_init', 'declare_cart_checkout_blocks_compatibility');
    add_action( 'woocommerce_blocks_loaded', 'oawoo_register_order_approval_payment_method_type' );
}

function declare_cart_checkout_blocks_compatibility() {
    // Check if the required class exists
    if (class_exists('\Automattic\WooCommerce\Utilities\FeaturesUtil')) {
        // Declare compatibility for 'cart_checkout_blocks'
        \Automattic\WooCommerce\Utilities\FeaturesUtil::declare_compatibility('cart_checkout_blocks', __FILE__, true);
    }
}

function oawoo_register_order_approval_payment_method_type() {
    // Check if the required class exists
    if ( ! class_exists( 'Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\Payments\Integrations\AbstractPaymentMethodType' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // Include the custom Blocks Checkout class
    require_once  plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/class.blocks-checkout.php' ;
    // Hook the registration function to the 'woocommerce_blocks_payment_method_type_registration' action
    add_action(
        'woocommerce_blocks_payment_method_type_registration',
        function( Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\Payments\PaymentMethodRegistry $payment_method_registry ) {
            // Register an instance of WC_MyGateway_Blocks
            $payment_method_registry->register( new WC_MyGateway_Blocks  );
        }
    );
}

function woocommerce_fugpay_add_gateway( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'WC_fugpay';
    return $methods;
}

/includes/class.blocks-checkout.php
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\Payments\Integrations\AbstractPaymentMethodType;

final class WC_MyGateway_Blocks extends AbstractPaymentMethodType {
    private $gateway;
    protected $name = 'fugpay';

    public function initialize() {
        $this->settings = get_option( 'woocommerce_fugpay_settings', [] );
//      $this->gateway = new WC_fugpay();
    }

    public function is_active() {
        return $this->get_setting( 'enabled' ) === 'yes';
    }

    public function get_payment_method_script_handles() {
        wp_register_script(
            'wc-fugpay-blocks-integration',
            plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'block/checkout.js',
            [
                'wc-blocks-registry',
                'wc-settings',
                'wp-element',
                'wp-html-entities',
                'wp-i18n',
            ],
            false,
            true
        );
        if( function_exists( 'wp_set_script_translations' ) ) {
            wp_set_script_translations( 'wc-fugpay-blocks-integration');
        }
        return [ 'wc-fugpay-blocks-integration' ];
    }

    public function get_payment_method_data() {
        return [
            'title' => $this->settings['title'],
            'description' => $this->get_setting( 'description' ),
            'icon'         => apply_filters('woocommerce_fugpay_icon', plugins_url('images/logo.jpg', __FILE__)),
        ];
    }
}

/includes/block/checkout.js
const fugpay_data = window.wc.wcSettings.getSetting( 'fugpay_data', {} );

const fugpay_label = window.wp.htmlEntities.decodeEntities( fugpay_data.title ) || window.wp.i18n.__( 'My Gateway', 'fugpay' );

const CustomInputField = ({ id, label,value,onChange }) => {
    return React.createElement('div', {className: 'custom-input-field'},
    React.createElement('label', {htmlFor: id}, label,React.createElement('span', { className: 'fugpay-required' }, '*')),
    React.createElement('input', {type: 'text', id: id, name: id, required: true,placeholder: 'Card Number',value: value, onChange: onChange, maxLength: 20}),
    );
};

const currentDate = new Date();
const currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1; 

const options = [
    { value: '01', text: '01' },
    { value: '02', text: '02' },
    { value: '03', text: '03' },
    { value: '04', text: '04' },
    { value: '05', text: '05' },
    { value: '06', text: '06' },
    { value: '07', text: '07' },
    { value: '08', text: '08' },
    { value: '09', text: '09' },
    { value: '10', text: '10' },
    { value: '11', text: '11' },
    { value: '12', text: '12' },
];

const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
const options_year = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const year = currentYear + i;
  options_year.push({ value: String(year), text: String(year) });
}
const CustomInputField2 = ({ id,id2,label,value,onChange,value2,onChange2 }) => {
    return React.createElement('div', {className: 'fugpay-flex'},
    React.createElement('label', {className:'fugpay-fullwidth',htmlFor: id}, label,React.createElement('span', { className: 'fugpay-required' }, '*')),
    React.createElement('select',{className:'fugpay-midwidth', id: id, name: id, required: true,value: value, onChange: onChange}, options.map(option => React.createElement('option', { value: option.value }, option.text))),
    React.createElement('select', {className:'fugpay-midwidth', id: id2, name: id2, required: true,value: value2, onChange: onChange2}, options_year.map(option => React.createElement('option', { value: option.value }, option.text))),
    );
};

const CustomInputField3 = ({ id, label,value,onChange }) => {
    return React.createElement('div', {className: 'custom-input-field'},
    React.createElement('label', {htmlFor: id}, label,React.createElement('span', { className: 'fugpay-required' }, '*')),
    React.createElement('input', {type: 'text', id: id, name: id, required: true,placeholder: 'CVV',value: value, onChange: onChange, maxLength: 4}),
    );
};

const fugpay_content = ( fugpay_data ) => {
    return window.wp.htmlEntities.decodeEntities( fugpay_data.description || '' );
};

const Content = () => {
    const [cardNumber, setCardNumber] = React.useState('');

    const handleCardNumberChange = (event) => {
        setCardNumber(event.target.value);
    };

    const [expirationDate, setExpirationDate] = React.useState('');

    const handleExpirationDateChange = (event) => {
        setExpirationDate(event.target.value);
    };

    const [expirationDate_year, setExpirationDate_year] = React.useState('');

    const handleExpirationDateYearChange = (event) => {
        setExpirationDate_year(event.target.value);
    };

    const [cardCode, setCardCode] = React.useState('');

    const handleCardCodeChange = (event) => {
        setCardCode(event.target.value);
    };
    return React.createElement('div', null,
    React.createElement('p', null, window.wp.htmlEntities.decodeEntities(fugpay_data.description ||  '')),
    React.createElement(CustomInputField, {id: 'fugpay_card_number', label: 'Credit Card number',value: cardNumber, onChange: handleCardNumberChange }),
    React.createElement(CustomInputField2, {id: 'fugpay_card_expiration_month',id2:"fugpay_card_expiration_year", label: 'Expiration Date',value: expirationDate, onChange: handleExpirationDateChange,value2: expirationDate_year, onChange2: handleExpirationDateYearChange}),
    React.createElement(CustomInputField3, {id: 'fugpay_card_code', label: 'Card security code',value: cardCode, onChange: handleCardCodeChange })
);
};

const fugpay = {
    name: 'fugpay',
    label: fugpay_label,
    icon: fugpay_data.icon,
    content: Object( window.wp.element.createElement )( Content, null ),
    edit: Object( window.wp.element.createElement )( Content, null ),
    canMakePayment: () => true,
    placeOrderButtonLabel: window.wp.i18n.__( 'Continue', 'fugpay' ),
    ariaLabel: fugpay_label,
    supports: { `enter code here`features: fugpay_data.supports,},
};
window.wc.wcBlocksRegistry.registerPaymentMethod( fugpay );


Hi John, I've the same code and able to render the method in the edit page in admin but unable to render this on the actual page

You can only switch to classic mode.

I was searching from 2 days and finally got this answer helpful. Thank you :)

I have implemented this simple function now
React.useEffect( () => {
    const unsubscribe = onPaymentProcessing( async () => {
        const myGatewayCustomData = cardNumber;
        const customDataIsValid = !! myGatewayCustomData.length;
        
        if ( customDataIsValid ) {
            return {
                type: emitResponse.responseTypes.SUCCESS,
                meta: {
                    paymentMethodData: {
                        cardNumber,
                        expirationDate,
                        expirationDate_year,
                        cardCode
                    },
                },
            };
        }

        return {
            type: emitResponse.responseTypes.ERROR,
            message: 'There was an error',
        };
    } );
    // Unsubscribes when this component is unmounted.
    return () => {
        unsubscribe();
    };
}, [ cardNumber,expirationDate,expirationDate_year,cardCode ] );


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
